# "ImportError: No module named Cython.Build" when running make file on Google Cloud

Tags: python, makefile, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a Google Cloud machine and need to run a make file. I do that by typing out `make` and the error that's returned is `ImportError: No module named Cython.Build`. However if I try to enter the same import statement in the interpreter (after typing `python`) I don't have any issues. **Why would the import statement not work when running a make file but work in the interpreter?**